# routing cause constructors to initializes twice

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have a strange issue where my default (welcome.component) rout component initialize twice. this is an issue because  welcome.component.html calls two more components menu and a tab. so if it initializes twice it will create two instances of my menu and tabs. To make things simple I took out all the parts of the application and I left only with app.component and welcome.component which still initialized twice. I am lost here and need some help

app.component.html

```
<home gwLinkID={{gwLinkID}} psnlUID={{psnlUID}} ntName={{ntName}}></home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I confirmed by running my debuger app.component is only called once

```
 export class AppComponent {
        @Input() gwLinkID: number;
        @Input() psnlUID: string;
        @Input() ntName: string;
        pageTitle: any[];

        errorMessage: string;

        constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
            this.gwLinkID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('gwLinkID');
            this.psnlUID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('psnlUID');
            this.ntName = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('ntName');


        }


    }
```

app.module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';

@NgModule({

    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }

        ]),


         CommonModule


    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, WelcomeComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

welcome.component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'welcome.component.html'

})
export class WelcomeComponent {
    @Input() gwLinkID: number;
    @Input() psnlUID: string;
    @Input() ntName: string;
    pageTitle: any[];

    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.gwLinkID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('gwLinkID');
        this.psnlUID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('psnlUID');
        this.ntName = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('ntName');


    }
}
```

welcome.component.html

```
  <!-- Logo of company -->
    <div class="logo text-center">

        <p>{{someVal}}</p>
    </div>

    <nav-menu [gwLinkID]="gwLinkID" [psnlUID]="psnlUID" [ntName]="ntName"></nav-menu>


</div>

<div class="main" style="height:100%">

    <div class="container" style="height:100%">
        <tab></tab>

    </div>
```

********************UPDATE*******************************************

Got it 
the issue is from here

app.component.html

```
<home gwLinkID={{gwLinkID}} psnlUID={{psnlUID}} ntName={{ntName}}></home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App.component is causing this issue so if I move app.component.html

and update my index.cshtml

```
<home gwLinkID=@ViewBag.GWLinkID psnlUID=@ViewBag.PsnlUID ntName=@ViewBag.NTName</home>
<ng-component></ng-component>
```

it works, however, this break another section in home.component all input values are undefined or null

```
  @Input() gwLinkID: number;
    @Input() psnlUID: string;
    @Input() ntName: string;
    pageTitle: any[];

    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.gwLinkID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('gwLinkID');
        this.psnlUID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('psnlUID');
        this.ntName = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('ntName');


    }
```

Comment: what is in your welcome.component.html ?

Comment: added the html page -ok the issue is from the constructor, when i remove the constructor it won't initialize twice. this is a problem because  my other components call services in the constructor and they are all called twice. I am LOST

Comment: only happens when i use routing , if routing are removed all constructors  are called once

Comment: I thought I got it , the issue sill there, when I add the routing constructors in components called twice

Comment: can you upload your project to github ?

Comment: it will take me sometime to do that, I think it has to do with the way router is in app.module, do you see anything wrong?

Comment: just updated my code, see update section, the issue was coming from app.component.html which caused all my components to initialize twice . I fixed it but it broke something else, since we know where the issue is do you have any ideas?